# intermittent iframe CORS error on back button

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, iframe, cross-domain

In my .NET MVC application I have a page containing an iframe which shares the same domain. In particular, the `src` attribute of the iframe is just a different action on the same MVC controller that serves the page.

On this page I include a small function named `resize` to adjust the height of the iframe as appropriate. I attach it like so:

```
const iframe = document.getElementById("my-iframe");

 iframe.onload =  function() {
     iframe.contentWindow.onresize = resize; 
 }
```

All this seems to work fine except for the following. Sometimes, though not always, if I navigate away from this page and then return to it using Chrome's back button, I get a CORS error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost" from accessing a cross-origin frame. at HTMLIframeElement.iframe.onload (http://localhost/.../.../123:865:47)
```

It seems like, even though both frames issue from `localhost`, the port number that is somehow being appended here runs afoul of CORS policy. (To be clear, the markup doesn't actually specify a port number anywhere.)

I have no idea why this happens only intermittently, or only when I use the back button, or what do about it. Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: Can you reproduce this problem in Firefox or Safari?

Comment: As far as I can tell, no. It's hard to completely rule out, since it only happens intermittently even on Chrome. But I haven't been able to reproduce it in other browsers.